# Querying empty(undefined) rows/columns from Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to query a class from Parse, but 1 column named(coverImage) can either be empty(undefined) or have an image in, depending on whether the user upload one!

I know how to get the rows with an image in, but I also need to download the other rows that have an empty coverImage as it contains over data...But so far I cannot seem to get the empty row without it crashing...

So I'm just wondering how can I get the data even if 1 column of the class is empty?

Here's my struct & Query:

```
 struct PostStruct {

        var dataType : Int = 0 // 0 for text, 1 for picture
        var date : NSDate
        var username : NSString
        var text : NSString?
        var title : NSString?
        var image : PFFile?
        var uuid : NSString
        var profileImage : PFFile
        var caption : NSString?
        var coverImage : PFFile?

        init (dataTypeInit: Int, dateInit : NSDate, usernameInit: String, textInit: String, titleInit: String, uuidInit: String,profileImageInit: PFFile, coverImageInit: PFFile) {
            dataType        = dataTypeInit
            date            = dateInit
            username        = usernameInit
            text            = textInit
            title           = titleInit
            uuid            = uuidInit
            profileImage    = profileImageInit
            coverImage      = coverImageInit
        }

        init (dataTypeInit: Int, dateInit : NSDate, usernameInit: String, imageInit: PFFile, uuidInit: String, profileImageInit: PFFile, captionInit: String) {
            dataType        = dataTypeInit
            date            = dateInit
            username        = usernameInit
            image           = imageInit
            uuid            = uuidInit
            profileImage    = profileImageInit
            caption         = captionInit

        }
```

Query :

```
 let query = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
                query.whereKey("username", containedIn: self.followArray)
                query.addDescendingOrder("createdAt")
                query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {

                        self.posts.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)


                                for object in objects! {


                            if let _ = object.valueForKey("textPost") as? String {
                                if object.valueForKey("coverImage") != nil {


                                // this must be a text post
                                var post = PostStruct(dataTypeInit: 0,
                                    dateInit: object.createdAt!,
                                    usernameInit: object.valueForKey("username") as! String,
                                    textInit: object.valueForKey("textPost") as! String,
                                    titleInit: object.valueForKey("titlePost") as! String,
                                    uuidInit: object.valueForKey("uuid") as! String,
                                    profileImageInit: object.valueForKey("profilePicture") as! PFFile,
                                    coverImageInit: object.valueForKey("coverImage") as! PFFile
                                    )


                                post.comments = comments

                                self.posts.append(post)
                                } else {
                                 print("jkh")
                                }

                                 } else {
                                // this must be an image
                                var post = PostStruct(dataTypeInit: 1,
                                    dateInit: object.createdAt!,
                                    usernameInit: object.valueForKey("username") as! String,
                                    imageInit: object.valueForKey("image") as! PFFile,
                                    uuidInit: object.valueForKey("uuid") as! String, profileImageInit: object.valueForKey("profilePicture") as! PFFile, captionInit: object.valueForKey("caption") as! String)

                                post.comments = comments

                                self.posts.append(post)
                            }}
```

If anyone can help me, thank you in advance!

Comment: where does the crash occur ?

Comment: @the_critic on this line, as there's no coverImage: coverImageInit: object.valueForKey("coverImage") as! PFFile

Comment: see my answer, I haven't tried it myself, but I think it should work.

Comment: hold on, I'll need to edit that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign the value optionally if it is set by adding `as?` (optional unwrapping) instead of `as!` (explicit unwrapping). That way, there will be an assignment of the value from `object.valueForKey()` if there is a value, otherwise it will be `nil`.

```
var post = PostStruct(
     dataTypeInit: 0,
     dateInit: object.createdAt!,
     usernameInit: object.valueForKey("username") as! String,
     textInit: object.valueForKey("textPost") as! String,
     titleInit: object.valueForKey("titlePost") as! String,
     uuidInit: object.valueForKey("uuid") as! String,
     profileImageInit: object.valueForKey("profilePicture") as! PFFile,
     coverImageInit: object.valueForKey("coverImage") as? PFFile
)
```

notice that there is a question mark after the `as` for the `coverImage`.

also for your init, you'll need to make the parameter optional:

```
init (dataTypeInit: Int, dateInit : NSDate, usernameInit: String, textInit: String, titleInit: String, uuidInit: String,profileImageInit: PFFile, coverImageInit: PFFile?) {
   // your init code (omitted for brevity)
}
```

Notice the question mark after the `PFFile` type for the `coverImageInit` parameter.